# Unhandled Runtime Error while following Shopify's React and Node Tutorial

Tags: node.js, shopify-app, ngrok

I keep getting this error while trying to open my app in my shopify test store.

AppBridgeError: APP::ERROR::INVALID_CONFIG: shopOrigin must be provided

Any and all help is appreciated

Answer (score -1):

I am having the same problem. This is following the Shopify https://shopify.dev/tutorials/build-a-shopify-app-with-node-and-react/build-your-user-interface-with-polaris
Dev tutorial.

Unhandled Runtime Error
AppBridgeError: APP::ERROR::INVALID_CONFIG: shopOrigin must be provided.

My code is exactly like in the tutorial. This is _app.js

```
    import App from 'next/app';
import Head from 'next/head';
import { AppProvider } from '@shopify/polaris';
import '@shopify/polaris/styles.css';
import { Provider } from '@shopify/app-bridge-react';
import translations from '@shopify/polaris/locales/en.json';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';


class MyApp extends App {
  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;
    const config = { apiKey: API_KEY, shopOrigin: Cookies.get("shopOrigin"), forceRedirect: true };
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Head>
          <title>Sample App </title>
          <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        </Head>
        <Provider config={config}>
          <AppProvider i18n={translations}>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </AppProvider>
        </Provider>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default MyApp;
```

Comment: I think I fixed the problem by just authenticating again. I restarted my server a few times and went on https://YOUR_NGROK_ADDRESS.io/auth?shop=YOUR_SHOPIFY_STORE.myshopify.com